spring boot gmail authentication failed
I implemented gmail service in spring boot. i configured spring.mail.password is app password but it still threw an exception
jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 98e67ed59e1d1-2bf80503816sm5287295a91.5 - gsmtp.
I have searched for a while but it's not work at all.
my application's configuration
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
    mail:
        host: smtp.gmail.com
        port: 587
        username: ${GMAIL_USERNAME}
        password: ${GMAIL_PASSWORD}
        properties:
            mail:
                transport:
                    protocol: smtp
                smtp:
                    auth: true
                    starttls:
                        enable: true
                        required: true

GMAIL_PASSWORD: qeripdncnmpfersq

here is my simple mail service:

@Service
public class MailService {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String from;

    @Async
    public void sendSimpleMail(String to, String subject, String content) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom(from);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(content);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }
}

mail controller
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppController {

    private MailService mailService;

    @PostMapping("/sendmail")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendEmail(@RequestBody String to){
       try{
           mailService.sendSimpleMail(to,"This is a simple mail","This is a simple mail");
           return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
       }
    }
}

i tried creating others app password, but nothing change. it still cannot connect.
